# Ember Simple Auth Promise

Tags: ember.js, devise, ember-simple-auth

I'm trying to handle an error messages with Ember Simple Auth, I'm using the devise extension.

File: `app/controllers/login.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import LoginControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/login-controller-mixin';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(LoginControllerMixin, {
  authenticator: 'simple-auth-authenticator:devise',
  identification: null,
  password: null,
  loginError: false,
  isSubmitting: false,

  actions: {
    authenticate: function() {
      var data = this.getProperties('identification', 'password');

      this._super(data);

      this.set('password', null);

      this.setProperties({
        loginError: true,
        loginResponse: 'login error'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

At the moment I always get the error message. I don't know how to show it only when an error occur. I have tried with

```
this._super(data).then(function({
    // Error handler
});
```

But then I get the error "_super() is undefined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above code you're always setting the error regardless of whether login is successful or not. What you would have to do is trigger the session authentication yourself:

```
this.get('session').authenticate(this.get('authenticator'), data).then(function() {
  …//success
}, function(error) {
  …//error
});
```

Comment: I added a change so in the next release `LoginControllerMixin#authenticate` will return the promise returned by the session so you can actually do this._super(data).then(function({ /*success*/ }, function({ /*error*/ });